# Does Affectiva support external USB camera for emmotion detection?

Tags: android, android-camera2

For some academic purpose i want to detect the user emotions from the USB external camera feed.So i would like to integrate the Affectiva SDK with my application. My question is is the **Affectiva** support the external USB camera?